# How can I add my own additional class to div id="content" in wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

This is my current tag.

`<div id="content" class="eleven columns" style="height: auto !important;">`

I want to add 2 extra classes to it

`<div id="content" class="eleven columns custom card" style="height: auto !important;">`

or

at least 1 additional class?

`<div id="content" class="eleven columns card" style="height: auto !important;">`

How can I add this to my blog theme? https://github.com/simplethemes/skeleton_wp

Is it better to add it via functions.php? Then what code should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a jquery function with wp_head hook in functions.php file of your child theme

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/